When creating an IAM user in AWS how to find out the ARN of the user during creation?

Go to AWS IAM
Click - Users
Click - Create User
Username: db-user
Click - Next
Have to choose an option
Add user to group
Copy permissions
Attach policies directly
Select - Attach policies directly
Click - Create Policy
Click - JSON
Paste suggested policy for connecting to a database from this article:

{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
      {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": [
             "rds-db:connect"
         ],
         "Resource": [
             "arn:aws:rds-db:us-east-2:1234567890:dbuser:db-ABCDEFGHIJKL01234/db_user"
         ]
      }
   ]
}


Change region: eu-west-2


Troubleshoot: Error: Invalid ARN Account

Since this user is not yet created - how do I replace the ARN account?

Given there are no ui helpers for this I just followed the advice from some other online examples and filled in the square bracket blanks.
Also instead of using IAM I used IAM Identity Center and created a permission set with custom inline policy and set the following arn which I could attach to a group and subsequently a user.
"arn:aws:rds-db:[REGION]:[AWS ROOT ACCOUNT ID]:dbuser:[database-resource-identifier]/[some_user_i_will_grant_permissionto_from_sql_statements]"
Credits: https://medium.com/@danielvaknin/connecting-to-aws-aurora-postgresql-database-using-aws-iam-identity-center-sso-ed8db57c1b0b
